# how can I display a dataBase Table in my multiple column comboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am using multi column in combo box. So,I would like to display a database table like this photo.
[image]

I tried the below coding but I get only the table date without the table borders.

```
private void affich()
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
            req = "select id_amort_fiscal+''+amort_fiscal as combined from amortissementFiscal;";
            SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand(req, connection);
            dr = new SqlDataAdapter(req, connection);
            dr.Fill(ds, "amortissementFiscal");
            multiColumnComboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables["amortissementFiscal"];
            multiColumnComboBox1.DisplayMember="combined";
            multiColumnComboBox1.ValueMember = "combined";

            connection.Close();
            return;
        }
```

this is what I get as a result:

[image]

any Help please and thanks :D

Comment: can someone helps me :(

Comment: What is this "multi-column combobox"?

Comment: Sir,it's shown in the first picture,it's a kind of ComboBox in which we can have more details (multi columns) concerning a specific object not one column as the standard comboBox :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this third party control?

Anyway your query is showing you are only picking 1 column. Try adding more columns in query.

```
private void affich()
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        // *******************
        // See the new_column2, new_column3 in the below query, replace them
        // with your own columns
        // ********************
        req = "select id_amort_fiscal+''+amort_fiscal as combined, new_column2, new_column3 from amortissementFiscal;";
        SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand(req, connection);
        dr = new SqlDataAdapter(req, connection);
        dr.Fill(ds, "amortissementFiscal");
        multiColumnComboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables["amortissementFiscal"];
        multiColumnComboBox1.DisplayMember="combined";
        multiColumnComboBox1.ValueMember = "combined";

        connection.Close();
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have assigned `ColumnToDisplay` property to your `MultiColumnCombobox`.

```
multiColumnComboBox1.ColumnsToDisplay = new String[] {"Combinded Fiscal", "First Name"};
```

This will bind your column data into particular column. To display the proper column header, I preferred to specify alias in your sql query and try to add more columns in your query.

```
req = "select (id_amort_fiscal+''+amort_fiscal) As [Combinded Fiscal], FName As [First Name] from amortissementFiscal;";
```